# How to show a current date element in every div having the same classname?

Tags: javascript

I would like to display a current date element  in every div having the same classname.

My code is below but it shows only once.

Could you some one help?

Thanks in advance.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = 'Updated ' + mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'updated';

span.textContent = today;
document.querySelector( ".current-date" ).prepend(span);
```

```css
.updated {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: coral;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="First" class="current-date">
  <h1>Hello First</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</section>
<hr>
<section id="Second" class="current-date">
  <h1>Hello Second</h1>
  <div>Nunc non aliquet ipsum sed hendreri</div>
</section>
<hr>
<section id="Third" class="current-date">
  <h1>Hello Third</h1>
  <div>Sed condimentum cursus elit</div>
</section>
```

Comment: try `document.querySelectorAll` to make a node list then loop over and prepend span.

Answer (score 0):

```js
cDate = document.querySelectorAll(".current-date");
for(var i = 0; i < cDate.length; i++){
  
  var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = 'Updated ' + mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.className = 'updated';
  span.textContent = today;
  
 cDate[i].prepend(span);

}
```

```css
.updated {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: coral;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="First" class="current-date">
  <h1>Hello First</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</section>
<hr>
<section id="Second" class="current-date">
  <h1>Hello Second</h1>
  <div>Nunc non aliquet ipsum sed hendreri</div>
</section>
<hr>
<section id="Third" class="current-date">
  <h1>Hello Third</h1>
  <div>Sed condimentum cursus elit</div>
</section>
```